# how to access array data from api in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to access an array by calling API in angular js. and use them in ng-repeat

angularcode:

```
$scope.onsubmit = function () {
    $scope.records = [];
    var answers = [];
    // Post your data to the server here. answers contains the questionId and the users' answer.
    $http.get('http://localhost/api/leaderboard/:quizId', answers).success(function successCallbac(data,status) {
        $scope.records = data;
         //console.log(records);
    });
};
```

Html code:

```
<div ng-repeat="list in records">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>{{list}}}</h3>
        <h3> {{ list}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I called an API in ng-click event ,I am receiving data from API but i cannot use them in ng-repeat records are not displaying in html instead it is showing the error:

```
 angular.js:12477 ReferenceError: records is not defined
```

how to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
$scope.records = data;
console.log(records);
```

Obviously the second line must be:

```
console.log($scope.records);
```

As records (just "records") is not defined outside of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Either change `console.log(records);` to `console.log($scope.records);` as mentioned in above comments as `records` is not defined, or comment the `console.log` line and it will work. It has nothing to do with `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

Here the record is actually a scope variable. So you can't use the variable simply as `records`. It should be always `$scope.records`

so change the code into

```
$scope.records = data;
    console.log($scope.records);
```

But if you want to use `records` as normal variable. You should declare it as `var records`

So the code will change to

```
var records = data;
    console.log(records);
```